# ReactDOM.render throws "Uncaught TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...).render"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've an react project.

The package.json contents are -

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  }
}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

The `index.js` file -

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react";

var reactElement = React.createElement('p', { id: 'param1' }, 'Hello from React');
ReactDOM.render(reactElement, document.getElementById('root'));
```

When I run the application with the command `npm start`, I'm expecting to see test `Hello from react`. But I'm getting error -

```
index.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...).render is not a function
    at ./src/index.js (index.js:5:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at startup:7:1
    at startup:7:1
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

The complete code is [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/react-ssr/tree/main/c2/my-app)

Comment: `import { ReactDOM } from "react-dom";` Your import is wrong

Comment: I updated the code still I get different error

Comment: import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);

Comment: write like that @RajkumarNatarajan

Answer (score 0):

Your import should be this:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```